# Вытащить значения из всех CheckBox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Существует N-ое кол-во чекбоксов (`checkbox`), на каждой странице оно всегда разное.
Использую плагин [iCheck](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck) с GitHub .

Задача, при отметке `checked` в чекбоксe отправлять с помощью JS значение его атрибута `value`.
Т.е. если отмечены 5 , 8 и 9 то `value` должен быть: `5 8 9`.

У меня же получается достать значение только из одного, последнего отмеченного чекбокса, даже если отмечены хоть 10 штук.

Мой код:

```
$('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var checkedValue = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(checkedValue);
    var itemsbought = document.getElementById(checkedValue).innerHTML;
    $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
});
```

В итоге у меня код

```
$('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
```

Срабатывает только 1 раз с 1 значением. А нужно, чтобы сработал со всеми значениями и столько раз, сколько отмеченных чекбоксов у меня есть..

Мучаюсь полтора часа, уже и циклы пихать пытался, пока без шансов.

Comment: покажите пожалуйста html код ваших чекбоксов

Comment: Уже решил проблему. Помогли на англ stack'e. Все оказалось просто.   var itemsbought=[];
  $('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  var checkedValue = $(this).attr('value');
  var v = document.getElementById(checkedValue).innerHTML;
  itemsbought.push(v);
  $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
  });

Comment: опубликуйте тогда ссылочку на тот пост - мало ли вдруг кто то еще искать будет))

Comment: @Anonymouse, в таких ситуациях вы можете оформить Ваше решение, как ответ на Ваш же вопрос

Comment: Ссылка на решение находится здесь:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668921/get-values-from-all-checkboxes-with-js?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Rolandius у вас есть некоторые ошибки в использовании внутристрочного `выделения кода`. Рекомендую прочитать вот эту инструкцию: [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1328)

Comment: @Anonymouse поскольку у вопроса есть метка [tag:javascript], то дублировать ее в заголовке необязательно. Вполне очевидно, что вам нужно решение именно с помощью JS, а не Ruby, например.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, не видел это сообщение!

Answer (score 1):

Если абстрагироваться от jQuery, можно вспомнить, что у форм есть замечательное свойство, позволяющее пробежаться по всем элементам. А вот и пример из http://www.w3schools.com :

```
var coffee = document.forms[0];
var txt = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
  if (coffee[i].checked) {
    txt = txt + coffee[i].value + " ";
  }
}
document.getElementById("order").value = "You ordered a coffee with: " + txt;
```